# Flutter web: How can I redirect assets to other domain?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I deploy flutter web html file on **https://a.com/**
and set  for cdn

so when i visit **https://a.com/#** it will load all js file on https://b.com/
BUT assets file still load from **https://a.com/** like **http://a.com/assets/assets/images/sub.png**

SO how can I tell flutter to found assets from **https://b.com/static/assets** ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load assets from other website that is not in your project, assets should be included in your project files before deployment.

If you want to use assets from another website you can use the Widget called Image.network() passing the url from your other website and load from network.

```
Image.network(
 "http://a.com/assets/assets/images/sub.png"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that i'm doing this is on AWS Amplify, since I'm not using cloudfront, assets are put on a different server that is hosted by CDN.

1. Ensure your host & target CDN are using the same protocol (http/https) since request are using xhr
2. If you wish to ensure faster loadtime, you can preload your assets also, using preloadjs, and put the asset list in a JSON file.
3. use .htaccess (located in your root folder) or amplify rule.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ https://b.com/static/assets/$1 [R=301,L]
```

while my AWS Amplify rule is :

```
[
    {
        "source": "/assets/<*>",
        "target": "https://b.com/static/assets/<*>",
        "status": "301",
        "condition": null
    }
]
```

you can test out htaccess rules via https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

This can vary from server to server (apache, nginx, AWS amplify) but they keyword to search will be "redirect a folder to another domain" or something similar.

You can't direct `Image.assets` to external link, as that will break the mobile app in flutter, unless you create your own method then break it down to separate web > `image.network` & mobile > `image.assets`.

This would be the case if you do not have access to the server.